# CSS Animate Content Bottom to Top

Tags: css

I have a div with a title, a description and a button. I want to show the title but hide the description and button until the user hovers over the div.

The problem I am having is that the description is dynamic and the number of lines can be different so you can see some of the content under the title.

```
.short-description-block {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(93,179,193, .7);
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(70%); /* push the content down but show the title */
    transition: all .5s ease;
    bottom: 0;
}

.block-content:hover .short-description-block {
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yourbudweiser/frxp1nq3/17/)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use the `calc()` css function to calculate the value in the initial `translateY`.

What you want is first know the height of the title. The title is an `h5` html element that have this styles that impact his height (just use the inspector to get them):

```css
h5 {
  font-size: 0.83em;
  margin-block-start: 1.67em;
  margin-block-end: 1.67em;
}
```

So the height of the title will be approximatively `.8em + (2 * 1.6em)`.

So now you want to translate `.short-description-block` so that just the title is visible. That can be done using:

```css
translateY(calc(100% - (.8em + (2 * 1.6em))));
```

Here is the example:

```css
.main-feature-block {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 49.5%;
}

.block-content {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.feature-image {
  background-position: center !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
  padding: 52% 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.short-description-block {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(93, 179, 193, .7);
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(calc(100% - (.8em + (2 * 1.6em))));
  transition: all .5s ease;
  bottom: 0;
}

.content {
  padding: 0px 35px 10px;
}

.main-feature-block .block-content:hover .short-description-block {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 main-feature-block">
  <div class="block-content">
    <div class="feature-image" style="background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150')"></div>
    <div class="short-description-block">
      <div class="content">
        <h5>Lorem Ipsum</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eu lacus euismod, finibus orci ut, interdum velit. Donec sit amet lorem et velit auctor commodo at non purus.</p>
        <div class="btn-content">
          <a class="c-btn" href="#" target="_self">Learn More</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 main-feature-block">
  <div class="block-content">
    <div class="feature-image" style="background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150')"></div>
    <div class="short-description-block">
      <div class="content">
        <h5>Lorem Ipsum</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eu lacus euismod, finibus orci ut, interdum velit. Donec sit amet lorem et velit auctor commodo at non purus.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eu lacus euismod, finibus orci ut, interdum velit. Donec sit amet lorem et velit auctor commodo at non purus.</p>
        <div class="btn-content">
          <a class="c-btn" href="#" target="_self">Learn More</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

&nbsp;
```

Comment: That works great when the title is one line but at smaller screen sizes the title breaks to two lines and it's getting cut off at the bottom.